# Problems installing Slidify in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, slidify

I am new to `R-programming` and I am trying to install `Slidify` and I am currently having a problem.  I am running on the below version of `RStudio`:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

I am using the below code to install Slidify:

```
install_github("slidify", "ramnathv")
install_github("slidifyLibraries", "ramnathv")*
```

I get the following error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
Username parameter is deprecated. Please use ramnathv/slidifyLibraries
```

I have also tried the below code to install `Slidify`:

```
pkgs <- c('ramnathv/slidifyLibraries', 'ramnathv/slidify')
devtools::install_github(pkgs)*
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Does anyone have experience installing `Slidify`?

Comment: Maybe you need to setup git in windows first?

Answer (score 1):

1) `install_github()` function is in `devtools` package, so first you have to install this package using `install.packages("devtools")`.

2) Then load the library using

```
library(devtools)
```

3) Now use your code

```
install_github("slidify", "ramnathv")
install_github("slidifyLibraries", "ramnathv")
```

It will work properly.